# Tableau racing bar chart with total

Tags: tableau-api

I am building a racing bar chart in Tableau, but am unable to show the label that will show the grand total independently within the sheet. I want this to work just like [the racing bar chart in Flourish](https://app.flourish.studio/@flourish/bar-chart-race).

[image: l want like this]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best way to achieve the grand total would be to have it in a separate worksheet and float the worksheet over your bar chart in a dashboard